# Why are the bounds of an UIView a CGRect and not a CGSize?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uiview, bounds

Is there a reason why the bounds property of `UIView` (an `NSView`) are a `CGRect` when the only information you'll ever want in that property are the size of that `CGRect`.

Is it just a shortcut for drawing since you'll need a `CGRect` when drawing? Or just a very specific special case where the `origin` of the `bounds` could be something else than `{0, 0}`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `frame` specifies where the view is relative to the superview, while `bounds` specifies where the view is allowed to draw relative to the frame.

By changing the `bounds` origin and/or width you can get clipping, e.g., or drawing outside of the view.

I.e, bounds origin is normally (0,0) but it must not be always so, like when you do clipping.

Furthermore, `bounds` is used by affine transformations instead of the `frame` and it represents the position after transformation which could also have an origin different from (0,0);

Answer (score 0):

### Bounds

bounds is inside of UIView means width and height.

(width,height);

### Frames

frame is where it should be start relative to its superview and its bounds

(from x,from y ,width,height);

starting point from superview + its bound